# I Want to get the token from my API by Dio flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, token, dio

**I'm trying to get my token from the API but it's empty**
**This is dio functions**

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

```
class DioHelper
{
  static  Dio dio;

  static init()
  {
    print('dioHelper Initialized');
    dio = Dio(
        BaseOptions(
      baseUrl:'my api link',
      receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
    ));
  }
  static Future<Response> getData ({
     String url,
    Map<String,dynamic> query,
    String lang = 'en',
    String token,
    Map<String,dynamic> data,
  })async
  {
    dio.options.headers =
    {
      'lang':'$lang',
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'Authorization' : '$token'
    };
    return await dio.get(
        url,
        queryParameters: query
    );
  }

  static Future<Response> postData ({
  String url,
    Map<String,dynamic> query,
    Map<String,dynamic> data,
    String lang = 'ar',
    String token
  })async
  {
    dio.options.headers =
    {
      'lang':'$lang',
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'Authorization' : '$token'
    };
    return await dio.post(
        url,
        queryParameters: query,
        data: data,

    );
  }

  static Future<Response> putData ({
    String url,
    Map<String,dynamic> query,
    Map<String,dynamic> data,
    String lang = 'ar',
    String token
  })async
  {
    dio.options.headers =
    {
      'lang':'$lang',
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'Authorization' : '$token'
    };
    return await dio.put(
      url,
      queryParameters: query,
      data: data,
    );
  }

  static Future<Response> deleteData ({
 String url,
    String lang = 'ar',
    String token
  })async
  {
    dio.options.headers =
    {
      'lang':'$lang',
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'Authorization' : '$token'
    };
    return await dio.delete(url);
  }
}
```

*and pass value in this variable*

```
String token = '';
```

**and fuctions sharedPreferences**

```
  import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class CacheHelper
{
  static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  static init () async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  static dynamic getData(String key, ){
    return sharedPreferences.get(key);
  }

  static Future<bool> saveData({ String key, dynamic value})async{
    if(value is String) return await sharedPreferences.setString(key, value);
    if(value is int) return await sharedPreferences.setInt(key, value);
    if(value is bool) return await sharedPreferences.setBool(key, value);
    return await sharedPreferences.setDouble(key, value);


  }

  static Future<bool> removeData (String key)async{
    return await sharedPreferences.remove(key);
  }

}
*CALL THE TOKEN*
    Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();
  await DioHelper.init();
  await CacheHelper.init();
  token = CacheHelper.getData('token');
  var IsLogin = CacheHelper.getData( 'IsLogin');
  var IsBoarding = CacheHelper.getData( 'IsBoarding');
  print(IsLogin);
  print(IsBoarding);
  print(token);
  var widget;
  if (IsBoarding != null) {
    if (token == null) {
      widget = ShopingScreen();
    } else {
      widget = Login_Screen();
    }
  } else {
    widget = BordScreen();
  }
```

*THANKS*
**Is there any solution**

****I described my problem a few days ago, but without details, there was no useful solution****
*Tried a lot but it didn't solve this problem. I tried wiping the phone data or reformatting the codes and restarting the device several times.*

Comment: Where is the _actual_ call you are having issues with and what is it _actually_ returning?

Comment: the getData and i need the token

Comment: It would also help to know what API you are trying to communicate with. Is it your own personal API or is it a public API with publically available documentation?

Comment: void GetData() async {
    emit(LoadingHomeData());
    await DioHelper.getData(url: Home_, token: token).then((value) {
      homedata = Home.fromjson(value.data);
      homedata!.data!.products.forEach((element) {
        fa!.addAll({element.id: element.Favorites});
      });

Comment: This code is supposed to come from getData after I call it via main , then I can pass it to my stored variable and then I can get it from SharedPreferences and then I decide if I can go home or not but the value is always null